# v-for render after AJAX request

Tags: ajax, vue.js, render, v-for, ajax-polling

I have a main page containing a component called `single-contact` as below:

```
<el-row id="rowContact">
  <!-- Contacts -->
  <el-scrollbar wrap-class="list" :native="false">
    <single-contact ref="singleContact"></single-contact>
  </el-scrollbar>
</el-row>
```

And I want to dynamically render this component after AJAX polling, so in `SingleContact.vue` I use `$axios` and `mounted()` to request the data from the backend. And I want to render the component using `v-for`. I have my code as:

```
<template>
  <div :key="componentKey">
    <el-row id="card"  v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.convUsername">
      <div id="avatar" ><el-avatar icon="el-icon-user-solid"></el-avatar></div>
      <h5 id='name' v-if="contact">{{contact.convUsername}}</h5>
      <div id='btnDel'><el-button size="medium" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete" v-on:click="delContact(contact.convUsername)"></el-button></div>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the data structure is:

```
data() {
  return {
    timer: null,
    contacts: []
  }
```

And the method of Ajax polling is:

```
loadContacts () {
    var _this = this
    console.log('loading contacts')
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('username'))

    this.$axios.post('/msglist',{
      ownerUsername: localStorage.getItem('username')
    }).then(resp => {
      console.log('success')
      var json = JSON.stringify(resp.data);
      _this.contacts = JSON.parse(json);
      console.log(json);
      console.log(_this.contacts[0].convUserName);
      // }
    }).catch(failResponse => {
      console.log(failResponse)
    })
  }
```

This is what I get in the console:
[Console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG5uY.jpg)
And the mounted method I compute is as:

```
beforeMount() {
  var self = this
  this.$axios.post('/msglist',{
    ownerUsername: localStorage.getItem('username')
  }).then(resp => {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      self.contacts = resp.data
    })
  }).catch(failResponse => {
    console.log(failResponse)
  })
},
mounted() {
  this.timer = setInterval(this.loadContacts(), 1000)
  this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.loadContacts()
  })
},
beforeDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.timer)
  this.timer = null
}
```

I can get the correct data in the console. It seems that the backend can correctly send json to the front, and the front can also receive the right result. But the page just doesn't render as expected.

Any advice would be great! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try add a v-if=contacts.length > 0 on the parent container. So that the component wont render before data has been fetched.

Comment: @Cerceis Thank you for your reply! I've tried this but it's still not working. But I found if I changed the element to render from ```<h5 id='name'>{{contact.convUserName}}</h5>``` to ```<h5 id='name'>{{contact.index}}</h5>```, the page would be right. Is it a issue about the use of ```String``` and ```Integer```?

Comment: You spelled your variable wrong. ```contact.convUserName``` not ```contact.convUsername```

Comment: omg Thank you! Now it works!